# Deploy ASP.NET core 7 Web API with React front end

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I wrote an ASP.NET Core 7 web API backend and standalone Javascript React front end. I can deploy the backend to IIS successfully and it works fine through postman. However when I try to deploy the react front end using the method described in this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022
my visual studio just freaks out and crashes. I am trying to figure out how to deploy the front end manually without using the visual studio publish feature.

This is my project setup:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cApdk.png

And this is the IIS side where the WEB API backend is currently published:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtJ9O.png

Do I need to create a separate site for the frontend or can I deploy it to the same site as the backend? How can I build the frontend and manually deploy to the IIS?

Answer (score 0):

For the site to work properly, you should build the frontend part in production mode, i.e. use the command npm run build instead of npm run start.
And then move the resulting files to the wwwroot folder inside your NET7 project.

Additionally, you should add static files using the AddStaticFiles method.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Also remember to set the ports correctly, because you can have different ones in the development and production environment, you will do it in launchsetting.json

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your Program.cs file like below, the you could publish webapi project directly.  Every step mentioned in the official document must be completed, and finally add the following code.

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.

            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseDefaultFiles();
                //app.UseStaticFiles();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            //app.MapControllers();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                // Add this line
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");
            });

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

**Test Result**

[image]